# on item click, items re-renders and scroll comes to the top which is undesired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have made a component where I am rendering grids of items. On clicking one item, the item is being selected. However there are many items present so there is scroll bar. Whenever I click on an Item, the component is re-rendered (as I am putting the selectedItem in my state), which further re-renders all the other items. But when I click an item after scrolling to the bottom (or middle), the component renders to the top, however I want that to remain on the position it was being clicked.

The components are as follows :

```
Full-Screen (made using react-portal, contains onClick and changes its state)
    --TilesView (all tiles wrapper which renders all the tiles and has an ajax call)
        --all Tiles (single tile element)
```

The part code is as follows :

FullScreen:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.selectedPost) {
      this.setState({
        selectedPost: {
          [this.props.selectedPost[0]]: true
        }
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    const that = this;
    //Todo: User fullpage header when space is updated
    return (
      <Portal container={() => document.querySelector('body')}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <FullPageForm onHide={that.props.onCancel} closeIcnLabel={'esc'} bgDark={true}>
            <FullPageForm.Body>
              <span className={styles.header}>{'Select Post'}</span>
              <div className={styles.body}>
                <ExistingAssets onCreativeTileClicked={this.handlePostClick}
                                selectedCreatives={this.state.selectedPost}
                                showSelectedTick/>
              </div>
            </FullPageForm.Body>
          </FullPageForm>
        </div>
      </Portal>
    );
  }

  handlePostClick = (adCreativeAsset, id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      selectedPost: {
        [id]: adCreativeAsset
      }
    });
  }
```

In my handlePostClick, I tried doing `event.preventDefault()` but it didn't work. I have no clue why this is happening, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `handlePostClick` definition to

```
handlePostClick = (e, adCreativeAsset, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //blah blah what you want
}
```

and in your JSX change `onCreativeTileClicked={this.handlePostClick}` to `onCreativeTileClicked={this.handlePostClick.bind(this)}`.

The event you were prevent-defaulting (stopping propagation in real terms) isn't the real event coming from the click but a synthetic one that can be summoned to fill in for an event when there isn't one. You need to stop propagation for the real event.
Hope this helps.